# Множественное наследование шаблонного класса

Tags: c++

Есть класс

```
template<int T>
class E
{
    template<typename ... Args>
    class Base
    {
    public:
        virtual void do(Args ... args) = 0;
    };
};
```

Есть еще класс

```
class A : public E<0>::Base<int>,
          public E<1>::Base<int>
{
public:
    // я хочу тут определить методы базовых классов

    void E<0>::Base<int>::operator()(int val) override
    {
        std::cout << val << std::endl;
    }  

    void E<1>::Base<int>::operator()(int val) override
    {
        std::cout << val*val << std::endl;
    }   
};
```

Все это затевалось, чтобы потом можно было вызывать методы вот так:

```
A a;
a::E<0>::Base<int>::(1); // Тут, возможно, синтаксис не правильный,
a::E<1>::Base<int>::(1); // надо явно написать operator, но не суть
```

Но я получаю ошибки подобного плана, говорящие, что нельзя вот так взять и явно указать предка метода

```
error: cannot define member function 'E<0>::Base<int>::operator()' within 'A'
 void E<0>::Base<int>::operator()(int val) override
```

Как можно еще определить тела этих методов, чтобы они компилировались и работали?

Comment: @Abyx, На основе этого я хочу сделать у себя обработку событий. Если класс наследует E<T>::Base<...>, значит он реализует обработку события T с сигнатурой, указанной в параметрах Base. Из-за этого я могу в любом месте программы работать с обработчиками нужных мне событий (указателями на них), совсем не задумываясь об их реализации

Answer (score 0):

Как это сделать напрямую, я не придумал, поэтому сделал на основе перегрузки функций.

В базовом классе я определяю оператор, который вызовет метод из наследника, прокинув в него все параметры + нулевой указатель своего типа (чтобы однозначно вызвался именно он)

```
template <int T>
class E
{
public:
    template <typename ... ArgTypes>
    class Base
    {
    public:
        void operator()(ArgTypes ... args)
        {
            On(nullptr, args...);
        }
        virtual void On(Base<ArgTypes...>*, ArgTypes...) = 0;
    };
};
```

В наследнике я просто наследуюсь от необходимых классов и реализую нужные виртуальные функции

```
class A : public E<0>::Base<int>
        , public E<1>::Base<int>
{
public:

    void On(E<0>::Base<int>*, int val) override
    {
        std::cout << "E<0>::Base<int> called: " << val << std::endl;
    }  

    void On(E<1>::Base<int>*, int val) override
    {
        std::cout << "E<1>::Base<int> called: " << val*val << std::endl;
    }  
};
```

И дальше я могу вызывать необходимые функции базовых классов

```
int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<A> a = std::make_shared<A>();
    a->E<0>::Base<int>::operator()(2);
    a->E<1>::Base<int>::operator()(2);

    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/FopomV